# running monerod on background thread always stops after some time

Tags: monerod, linux, background

When I run monerod on a background fork in linux, it always stops after sometime. Why is this? I have tried using **monerod --detach** and **nohup monerod &** and it still stops after awhile. I can't complete a full sync as a result. Does anyone know why this is happening ?

Comment: Give the version of monerod you're using, and whether you're getting an OOM kill (check dmesg).

Comment: monero-v0.11.1.0 but I solved the problem. Was caused becuase it was running on a child process from a remote shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being because I was running monerod on a child process via remote shell in which case one should use screen to keep the process running should there be a disconnection or run on a system owned background process